# How do i implement try /catch & exception handling on my code? I am new to typescript and cant find good solutions

Tags: typescript, testing, exception, mocha.js, chai

This is my 'it' block and i want to implement exception handling using try catch block.What is the best standard structure for such kind of test cases.Please suggest me .

```
it('To verify obligatory params with a query as a typo', function(done) {

    for (let j=0; j<languages.length;j++) {

        for (let i = 0; i < gender.length; i++) {

            for (let k = 0; k < query.length; k++) {

                chai.request(server)
                    .get('/autocomplete?language=' + languages[j] + '&country=ca&query=' + query[k] + '&gender=' + gender[i])
                    .end(function(err: any, response: any) {
                        should.equal(err, null);
                        //Basic end point assertion
                        response.should.have.status(200);
                        response.should.be.json;


                        expect(response.body.brands.length).to.be.greaterThan(0);
                        //console.log("verified autocomplete/fuzziness for query="+query[k]+ ",language=" + languages[j] + " for gender=" + gender[i])

                    });
            }
        }
    }

    console.log("Verified autocomplete/fuzziness for different languages");

});`
```

Comment: Which line of code has the potential to throw the exception that you want to handle?

Comment: You don't need try/catch here. When the response comes back and .end is called it will run the function. If there is an error then "err" will be non null.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen These can throw exceptions
1.request.get , 
2.request.end , 
3.status 200  test

Comment: For #1 and #2, you could insert `try {` before the `chai.request(server)` and `} catch (e) { /*error handling code*/ }` after the `});`.  But I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, so this may not be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks @MattMcCutchen